# Keycloak authentication at load balancer level

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am working on keycloak authentication and authorization. I want to authenticate user on load balancer level. Is it possible to filter out user before checking for an actual application authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need layer 7 load balancer with OIDC/SAML support, e.g. F5, AWS ALB, ...

Comment: Thanks for your response Jan. we are using Big IP but it is not maintained by my organisation so we don't have access to check or add any configuration. Any other way to do this? Is it possible to check the oidc scopes at virtual host level?